# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Main/[object Object]' is not allowed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

Jquery call:

```
$.post({
        url: "http://localhost:60700/Main//Data/dataServices.aspx",
        data: { action: "savePhoneData", phoneID: PhoneID, values : JSON.stringify(allData) },
        success: phoneSaved,
        error: phoneSavedFailed
    });
```

I have similar functions in the project that use the **GET** method and work just fine.
In this case, however, **POST** must be used due to the amount of data.

The error I get is: The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Main/[object Object]' is not allowed.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a .NET expert but it seems like that specific servlet does not support post.

Answer (score 0):

I used an ASMX page instead:

```
public class Handsets : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string Test(object items)
        {
            List<object> lstItems = new JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType<List<object>>(items);
            return "wow";
        }
    }
```